# Rounded Line Shader

Tags: unity, shaders

I am trying to achieve a rounded Line where Line will go through point A to point B with GLSL. I am able to do it on Shader Graph however I don't want to create my project while using Universal Render Pipeline since it is increasing the size of the project.

I also tried to generate the code from a test project using Shader Graph; however, importing was successful for my project using the built-in renderer.

Does anyone know how I can achieve a rounded line on GLSL?

[image]

Comment: Rather than creating a custom shader, have you tried using Unity's built-in Line Renderer, or using a SpriteRenderer set to Sliced mode?

Comment: Can you show the shader graph you're using that you need help translating? I think Unity will even generate the shader code for you to copy and paste if you want.

Comment: FWIW, as of Unity 2021.2 ShaderGraph *does* support the Built-in Render Pipeline.